# Is publish_actions extended facebook permission suitable for automatically publishing?

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook

I want to do have a checkbox "Share to facebook" on my form, that if checked, automatically sends it to facebook, reducing the need for a popup. Which facebook extended permission do I need to acquire for this? I can't figure out which one it is? Will publish_actions be correct? Or is this overkill?

Also, I want to be non-invasive for the user, I've notice Tripadvisor handles this well they have a "Sharing On", "Sharing off" mode, + they additionally ask you again with a popup each time. Does anyone know why they have "Sharing On/Off" if it doesn't do anything? I'd like to have this On/Off system but how does it work exactly?

Answer (score 2):

`publish_action` permissions allow you to post OpenGraph actions and object. These are automatically posted, publication of OG are re kept in a ticker box on user profile and can appear in the news feed. Most Facebook application use OG actions as they're less intrusive and more interesting from the story telling view point.

If what you want is to publish a post to wall; like an image sharing or a website. Then you'll want `publish_stream` permissions, and you'll want to create new `post`. This is basically what the sharing FB widget or the user sharing a link does. I'd advocate against using this one as it is intrusive and may bring you bad feedback (for spam) - and in the end, you'll just get blocked by FB.

So, look out OpenGraph and see if it matches your needs. If not, then prefer using really clear sharing functionnality at the cost of an extra popup as this will make it clear to the user and prevent bad feedback from bringing down you app.